# Selenium Chrome C# doesn't work if browser is minimized

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I integrated Selenium Chrome driver with my little .NET application. I'm doing automation on a google page. All is working fine and as expected as long as the browser is **visible** or in the **background**. If I **minimize** it it stops before doing any work. I have a lot of code with lots of **DISPLAYED** tests:

```
        var collection = cdriver.FindElements(By.TagName(@"input"),10);
        //var collection = cdriver.FindElementsByClassName("gwt-TextBox");
        bool found = false;
        IWebElement texter = null;
        do
        {
        foreach (IWebElement element in collection)
        {
            if(element.GetAttribute("class").ToString() == "gwt-TextBox" ) 
            {
                if(element.Displayed==true) { found = true; texter = element; }
            }   
        }
        } while(!found);
        texter.SendKeys(readerCSV.apkTitle);
```

Is there a way for me to minimize the chrome window so all the code that is working fine when the window is maximized or visible will also work fine with it minimized ? **Enabled** tests don't work as expected.

Another example:

```
    var btnUpload = cdriver.FindElement(By.Id("gwt-uid-170"),10);
    btnUpload.Click();
```

The above btnUpload.click() code gives me **QpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException**

Is there a startup option for the chrome driver so I can start the window without the minimize button?

Comment: Well what errors do you get?

Comment: QpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException

Comment: Just don't click on it!

Comment: Post this as an answer , I'll accept it!

Answer (score -1):

Chrome has to be pulled up because the driver is checking to make sure that the element is visible/enabled/etc to the user. Just stop minimizing it and let it run in the background and it will work.

Comment: what's the issue here?